# Does it make sense to say "recorded an ever-growing collection"?

Tags: word-usage

Can one write the following?

> Since January 19, 1919, Some Band has recorded an ever-growing collection of original pieces of music.

I have doubts because with "recorded" it sounds as if the action is complete while "ever-growing" tells the reader the opposite.

What are better/other ways to tell if there's a significant and constantly increasing number of items in a collection?

Comment: I think you misunderstand the use of *recorded.* Each single musical composition can be referred to as a *recording.*

Comment: @Davo thanks, I changed Studio to Band. Hopefully it makes the example more clear.

Comment: That does not affect the meaning of *recorded* at all. They **record** each song, and each one adds to the ever-growing collection.

Comment: I agree with your sense of completion; I'd use ' ... have been recording ...'.

Comment: @Davo it is exactly the meaning I'm after, but I want to know if it can be expressed like I did in my example.

Comment: As a native speaker I tend to agree with @EdwinAshworth, "recorded" does convey the idea of a completed process.

Comment: Yes, *have been recording* makes more sense.

Comment: It's messy, because "recorded" has more than one sense at play in the quotation.  The original is not wrong, though some might prefer a different wording.

Comment: "have been recording" suggests they've been recording continuously since 1919, rather than the way the recording process actually works (band goes into studio for a few days per year).

Answer (score 1):

Since January 19, 1919, Some Band ***has been recording*** an ever-growing collection of original pieces of music.

This shows that the collection is in the process of being expanded.

Comment: That suggests they're recording continuously, "has recorded" is fine if they do it from time to time.

Comment: @StuartF: no, it doesn't. "I have been going to France since 1999" doesn't mean that I'm on a very slow ocean liner.

Answer (score 0):

English normally puts an adjective modifying a noun or noun-phrase before but adjacent to what is being modified. Therefore, the normal sense of "_ has recorded an ever-growing collection of original pieces" is that the number of original pieces in that collection is growing. Thus, I think it very unlikely that it could be interpreted as referring to increasing fabrication of physical items that encode performance of some or all of that music, or as referring to an increasing number of performances that have been recorded.

If you are worried about possible confusion among original pieces of music, performances, or physical media, you could substitute "write" or "record from" for "record."

What does sound off to my ear is a slight mismatch between the tense of "has recorded" and the denotation of "ever growing."

I'd suggest "_ has been recording from an ever growing collection ..." That phrasing suggests that the process of recording started in the past, but has not necessarily ceased, a state of affairs perfectly consistent with a still increasing collection of original music.

In short, I am less concerned with the use of "record" as a root verb as I am by the tense chosen.

Answer (score 0):

Your (grammatical but semantically flawed) sentence is analogous to:

> The construction company has been digging an ever-growing mound of dirt.

Digging creates a pit, not a mound.  You would need to make that into two clauses:

> The construction company has been digging an ever deeper and wider pit, in that process producing an ever-growing mound of soil and rocks.

> Some Band has been recording since 1919, amassing a truly  impressive collection of original music.

Just as **digging** cannot do "double-duty", referring both to the individual acts and the accumulation that results, **recording** cannot refer to the individual acts and the collection that results.  But you can establish an integral link between the two, discrete actions and their accumulated result, with a participial clause following upon the matrix clause.

Answer (score -1):

I would rephrase this as follows:
"Some Band has been building a repertoire of original music since 1919."
OR
"Since 1919, Some Band's collection of original recorded music has steadily grown."

Comment: That's not what repertoire means: "a list or supply of dramas, operas, pieces, or parts that a company or person is prepared to perform" not a set of recordings.